# Get the resorted array from angularjs ng-repeat expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Suppose I have the following angularjs expression

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:age">
```

Suppose in my controller, I want to get the first 5 people in this newly sorted list. How can I do that?

I'm hoping there's some $scope variable that's injected that I can retrieve.

Otherwise, I suppose in my controller, I can apply the same sort and get the first five, but it seems inefficient to apply the sort twice. Anyone know how I would do it in javascript anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as` which will return the filtered array as a scope variable:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:age as filteredPeople">
```

Note this wasn't available in early versions of angular

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use this syntax to create a new variable based off your filters:

```
ng-repeat="person in filtered = (people | orderBy:age)"
```

`$scope.filtered` now exists as the ordered array.